# OEM control center features for laptops on Linux?

Tags: windows, keyboard

Many laptops that come with Windows pre-installed.
Manufacturers also implement some special control centers with features and controls such as:

- Keyboard backlight brightness and colours (common on high-end notebooks).
- Some mouse settings and touchpad.
- Power settings.
- Graphics settings.
- Sound settings.

OEMs such as MSi, Samsung, Lenovo, etc. have their own individual control centers.

**How can these features also be controlled on Linux?**

Comment: This is usually part of your desktop environment and the way this works depends on what graphical desktop environment you use. Is your issue that you can't find these controls?

Comment: @Kusalananda I think this is referring to fleet-management software, usually related to vPro and similar features.